# replicate merging and frequency calculation of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that I would like to do three simple, yet non obvious things to it:

count the amount of times a string repeats in the "name" column and record it in a new column. Add the value in the "stop" column together when a duplicate is found, and finally, remove every subsequent row that string is in.

For example I have:

```
dim(df)
[1] 80000      2

head(df, 4)
    name          stops       
1 dowewewg.1          1 
2 cat.1               1    
3 dowewewg.1          1    
4 cat.1               2
```

The output should be

```
   name           stops    frequency
1 dowewewg.1          2       2
2 cat.1               3       2
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split/apply/combine to solve this. Here's an approach that uses `split` to split by `name`, `lapply` to compute the summary statistics for each group, and `do.call` with `rbind` to combine all the results.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$name), function(x) {
  data.frame(name=x$name[1], stops=sum(x$stops), frequency=nrow(x))
}))
#                  name stops frequency
# cat.1           cat.1     3         2
# dowewewg.1 dowewewg.1     2         2
```

Comment: thanks. It turns out this takes extremely long in R. Any idea how to implement this in python?

Comment: @user3141121 if you want to do this in python instead of R, I would post a new question tagged with the python tag so that community can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an additional approach

```
# read in the data
df<-read.table(text="
name          stops       
1 dowewewg.1          1 
2 cat.1               1    
3 dowewewg.1          1    
4 cat.1               2 ",
header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Now:

```
newdf <- data.frame(
 stops = tapply(df$stops, df$name, sum),
 frequency = as.vector(table(df$name)))
#           stops frequency
#cat.1          3         2
#dowewewg.1     2         2
```

If you want a `name` column:

```
newdf$name <- rownames(newdf)
#           stops frequency       name
#cat.1          3         2      cat.1
#dowewewg.1     2         2 dowewewg.1
```